# Passing data to .net web services and getting results back?

Tags: c#, android, .net, web-services

I am in need of an effective example/tutorial on how to pass input data from Android to .net web services and for retrieval of results to Android applications.

Please share any links to guides, examples, tutorials that you may feel relevant to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a Rest Webservice and here is a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) ,you can pass input data using URI and you should plan how your URI should be for example to post a customer name :

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/post-customer/{name}")]
        void postCustomer(string name);
```

to get customer data using customer id :

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/get-customer/{id}")]
        Customer getCustomer(string id);
```

then and after hosting your webservice you need to access it from your android app using HTTP Client for example :

```
String uri = "uri to your service";
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);  
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
String result = null;
try {  
    result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

after that you should have a string in "result" and this string represent your response (json or xml).

hope this info can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here give the small sample try this for post

public void post(String appid,String custlogid,String cityareaid,String mosqname,String mosqid,String lat,String lon){

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(globalconstant.URL_mosquepost); 
        UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
        // Add your data   
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);   
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("APPUDID", appid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CUSTLOGID", custlogid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CITYAREAID", cityareaid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CITYMOSQUENAME", mosqname));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CITYMOSQUEID", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LATITUDE", lat));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", lon));
        try {
            form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
             httppost.setEntity(form);
            Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"\n"+EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```